# How to get the list of body co-ordinates in my box2d world in Processing

Tags: processing, box2d, jbox2d

I need to get the list of co-ordinates for my box2d world- I'm trying to get a wrap around effect so that particles that go off the side of the screen appear on the opposite side. box2d is not well documented for Processing and the only example I could find was in java (I know its the parent language but it needs translating). This is [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/08/23/box2d-and-the-wraparound-effect/).

I think the action is here:

```java
private function updateWorld(e:Event):void {
            world.Step(1/30,10,10);
            world.ClearForces();
            for (var b:b2Body=world.GetBodyList(); b; b=b.GetNext()) {
                if (b.GetType()==b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) {
                    if (b.GetJointList()==null) {
                        if (b.GetPosition().x*worldScale>640) {
                            b.SetPosition(new b2Vec2(0,b.GetPosition().y));
                        }
                        if (b.GetPosition().x*worldScale<0) {
                            b.SetPosition(new b2Vec2(640/worldScale,b.GetPosition().y));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            world.DrawDebugData();
        }
```

So I have tried translating this although I get stuck at the point of `world.GetBodyList`
I assume world is the instantiated box2d world I have created. I that is so, Processing doesn't seem to recognise this. Basically how to I just get an array of all the particle co-ordinates. Should be easier....

Answer (score 1):

Anything you can do in Java, you can do in Processing. But the code you posted is not Java. It's C++. (**Edit:** George pointed out that it looks like ActionScript. Either way, it's not Java!)

- **Box2D** is the original library, written in C++. Your code is an example of using that library.
- **JBox2D** is a Java wrapper of the C++ library, so you can write Java code that interacts with the C++ library.
- **Processing** is written in Java, so you can use JBox2D in Processing.
- Processing also has a few libraries that simplify JBox2D, like Daniel Shiffman's [**Box2D for Processing**](https://github.com/shiffman/Box2D-for-Processing) or [**BoxWrap2d**](http://www.jbox2d.org/processing/doc/index.html?org/jbox2d/p5/Physics.html).

**You don't need to use these libraries in order to use JBox2D from Processing.**

You can find the documentation for JBox2D [here](https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d).

To answer your question, yes, the `world` variable would be the instance of `World` you created when you set up your physics environment.

If you're using one of the Processing libraries, the creation of the `World` instance might be hidden from you. You might have to use JBox2D directly yourself.

Comment: Sebastian's snippet actually looks like Actionscript 3, not c++, but your advice is sound(+1)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks George. I don't know C++ at all, I just knew it wasn't Java! I've added a little note correcting myself.